# Conditional Read_Sql Dtype Change

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, dataframe, spyder

I'm having some issues with pulling a sql table into Python and hoping someone can help. I have a sql table with 40K+ rows, that I am trying to read into Python as a dataframe. All columns are currently formatted as varchar() in SQL, however, ProdID is being assigned as float64 (assuming because a majority of the records are numerical). The result is that a few of the records with alphanumerical values are showing as NaN in the dataframe. I've tried to force the dtype to str (see below code) with no success.

Sample SQL Table:

| Make | Model | ProdID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Toyota | Tundra | 1335 |
| Nissan | Titan | 2189 |
| Ford | F150 | 4751 |
| Chevy | Silverado | 2143 R1 |

Python Code:

```
SQL = "Select * from test_table"
conn = sql_connect(server,database)
dtype_prod = {'ProdID':str}
Query = pd.read_sql_query(SQL,con=conn,dtype=dtype_prod)
conn.close()
return Query
```

Python Dataframe Result:

| Make | Model | ProdID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Toyota | Tundra | 1335 |
| Nissan | Titan | 2189 |
| Ford | F150 | 4751 |
| Chevy | Silverado | nan |

Comment: One assumes you're pulling in numpy and using np.str here. Have you tried setting up the `dtype` dictionary to define all returned column types rather than just the problematic one?